# Email sent from website not going to domain specific email

Tags: php, email

I have a website with a contact form. The form just uses the php mail function to send the email but the email doesn't go to the email address if it is using the same domain name. I'm not sure what/how to explain.

If my website is www.example.com and someone fills out the contact form on this site, it should go to info@example.com but it doesn't. If I try using different email address that is not WHATEVER@example.com then it works fine.

Has anybody had a problem like this or can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to debug an issue like this.

I do not look after the email server but the company that does is saying everything is fine from their end and just keep saying there is something wrong with the form.

**Edit
I have checked spam folder and there is nothing
I have also tried sending emails to the email address from outside of the website (another email address)

Comment: Simple thing, but have you made sure to check spam folder and also sending a message to that address independent of the form.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have said I'd checked spam and emails do go to the address if not sent from the website

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest would be to change the email address your form is using to a different one, and try again - if the email goes through properly then, you know your code works, and there's a problem with the email address. Try a Yahoo / Hotmail / whatever address, just for testing.

Comment: Post the form and PHP code that's sending the mail.

Comment: I've already said that using another email works and the code works fine read the question!!

Comment: @DannyConnolly - then the next step is to add a BCC to the email you're sending to `info@`, and try again. Do you get that email?

Comment: Is there an SPF record preventing your web server from sending from your company domain?

Comment: I did a check on http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html and there does not appear to be any spf records set for the website